# Reference an Index for current status

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to have Excel take a column of text from one table and reference another table as an index of what value to enter back into the first table. Example:

**Table 1:**

```
Greg__Blue__5  
Cindy_Green_3
```

**Table 2:**

```
Green__ 3
Blue____5
```

I want to populate the third column with the number that lives in Table 2. So that I will have table two act more like an index as data changed in Table 1.

Comment: This is an extremely common task in Excel.  Have a look at the `VLOOKUP` function which will do exactly what you're looking for.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Have a look through Microsoft's list of [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb?CorrelationId=0ba59b0c-9691-4cae-870e-97436ec8514f&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA#__toc309306701).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Colour],Table2[#All],2,0)
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

I tried to figure out VLOOKUP on my own, but I kept going in circles trying to figure everything out.